# How to use @JsonIdentityInfo with composite PK?

Tags: java, jpa, jackson

If I have a class with a single `@Id` field I can use `@JsonIdentityInfo` like this:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
class Example {

    @Id
    int id;
    // getter setter
}
```

But if I have a composite PK class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(value = PointID.class)
public class Point {

    @Id
    private int x;
    @Id
    private int y;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PointID  implements Serializable {
    int x, y;
}
```

How do I use the annotation? In the above case the usage will be something like this

```
Point p = new Point(1,1);
object1.setPoint(p);
object2.setPoint(p);
bigObject.add(object1, object2);
```

and when I serialize `bigObject` I don't want to duplciate the point data but use its id like it does with the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `@JsonIdentityInfo` does not work with composite PK according to my attempts and online research.

Answer (score 4):

I searched Jackson documentation and source code and could not find support for object-id composed of multiple properties.

So my suggestion for you is to create such a composite key in a getter method:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(value = PointID.class)
public class Point {

    @Id
    private int x;
    @Id
    private int y;

    @JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "pk")
    public String getPk() {
        return x + "->" + y;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public int getX() {
        return x + "->" + y;
    }

    // @JsonIgnore on all individual properties that make pk
}
```

Comment: I've just tested this and the JSON representation is duplicated. I added `int a, b, c, d` to the `Point` class for testing and got this representation `{"x":1,"y":2,"a":0,"b":0,"c":0,"d":0,"pk":"1->2"}` everywhere the reference is used instead of only once and its PK all the other places.

Comment: add `@JsonIgnore` to the individual properties. see edited answer

Comment: Still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Main Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE_ENTRIES")
public class InvoiceEntry {

  @EmbeddedId
  private InvoiceEntryPK id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "A_COLUMN")
  private String aProperty;
  ...
  Getters and setters
  ...
}
```

PK Entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class InvoiceEntryPK {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER")
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, // Generic Property Generator
  property = "id", // Customer's ID property
  resolver = MyIdResolver.class, // My own IDResolver class
  scope = Customer.class)
  private Customer customer;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT")
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
  property = "id", // Product's ID property
  resolver = MyIdResolver.class,
  scope = Product.class)
  private Product product;
  ...
  Getters and setters
  ...
}
```

And now, the class MyIdResolver:

```
public class MyIdResolver implements ObjectIdResolver {
  private EntityManager em;
  public MyIdResolver(final EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
  }
  @Override
  public void bindItem(IdKey id, Object pojo) {
  }
  @Override
  public Object resolveId(IdKey id) {
    return this.em.find(id.scope, id.key);
  }
  @Override
  public ObjectIdResolver newForDeserialization(Object context) {
    return this;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean canUseFor(ObjectIdResolver resolverType) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now, you can deserialize this JSON:

```
{
  id: {
    customer: 72,
    product: 105
  },
  aProperty: "Some text..."
}
```